# javascript switch case not working properly?

Tags: javascript

i have the following code and i am using switch case to switch the src of the pictures with a button..  i don't know why the first case's **"alert"** is not functoning..

```
<div id="main_img">
   <center>
     <button style="width:100;height:100" onClick="LastPic();"><---</button>
     <img id="img" src="13.jpg" height=70% width=70%>
     <button style="width:100;height:100" onClick="FirstPic();">---></button>
</div>

<script>
   var james = document.getElementById("img").getAttribute('src');
   document.write(james);

   function FirstPic(){
      switch (james){
         case "12.jpg":
            document.getElementById("img").src = "13.jpg";
         break;
         case "13.jpg":
            document.getElementById("img").src = "14.jpg";
         break;
         case "larry": 
            alert('Hey');
         break;
         default: 
            alert('Default case');
         break;
     }
   }
</script>
```

Comment: `src` will return you the complete path `http://.../12.jpg`, use `getAttribute` instead.

Comment: ah, you are correct , friend... do i have to specify which attribute to get?

Comment: yeh..the `src` one...

Comment: i updated the code above, got it to switch to the first picture, but once i press the button again and run the function it will not let me switch the picture again..

Comment: Add `console.log(james);` before the `switch` statement so you can know if the attribute value is what you expect it to be.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the james variable is the same every time you call your function, it needs to be updated.

```
<div id="main_img">
<center>
<button style="width:100;height:100" onclick="LastPic();"><---</button>
<img id="img" src="13.jpg" height=70% width=70%>
<button style="width:100;height:100" onclick="FirstPic();">---></button>
<div id="imagesrc">13.jpg</div>
</div>
<script>
function FirstPic(){

var james = document.getElementById("img").getAttribute('src');
var imagesrc=document.getElementById('imagesrc');
switch (james)
{
   case "12.jpg":
james = "13.jpg";
break;

   case "13.jpg":
james = "14.jpg";
break;

   case "larry": 
       alert('Hey');
       break;

   default: 
       alert('Default case');
       break;
}
imagesrc.innerHTML=james;
document.getElementById('img').src=james;
}
</script>
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9sGxr/)

Answer (score 0):

add type of button **type="button"**

```
<button type="button" style="width:100;height:100" onClick="FirstPic();">---></button>
```

add attribute **type="button"** in button so page is not postback

Answer (score 0):

Try this its working fine.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
function myFunction()
{
var src = $('img[alt="example"]').attr('src');
alert("source of image with alternate text = example - " + src);

switch (src)
{
   case "12.jpg":
document.getElementById("img").src = "13.jpg";
break;

   case "13.jpg":
    alert('sa');
    document.getElementById("img").src = "14.jpg";
break;

   case "larry": 
       alert('Hey');
       break;

   default: 
       alert('Default case');
       break;
}
}
</script>
<div id="main_img">

<button style="width:100;height:100" onClick="LastPic();"><--- </button>
 <img alt="example" id="img" class="imagess" src="13.jpg" height=70% width=70%>
<button style="width:100;height:100" onClick="myFunction();">---></button>
</div>
```