# does a javascript function only run a variable once per refresh?? (switch: case)

Tags: javascript

I have a script I'm writing that runs a function to change a picture when a button is hit.  The following script changes the picture the first time, but the next time the very same script is run with different variables it doesn't seem to take the newest variable into account.

```
<div id="main_img">
<center>
<button style="width:100;height:100" onClick="LastPic();"><---</button>
<img id="img" src="12.jpg" height=70% width=70%>
<button style="width:100;height:100" onClick="FirstPic();">---></button>
 </div>

<script>
var james = document.getElementById("img").getAttribute('src');

document.write(james);

function FirstPic() {
    switch (james) {
    case "12.jpg":
        document.getElementById("img").src = "13.jpg";
        break;

    case "13.jpg":
        document.getElementById("img").src = "14.jpg";
        break;


    default:
        alert('Default case');
        break;
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript switch case not working properly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17779727/javascript-switch-case-not-working-properly)

Comment: I just answered this in his first question which is exactly the same, which solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
var james = document.getElementById("img").getAttribute('src');
document.write(james);

function FirstPic()
{
    // Get the new value every time the function is called
    james = document.getElementById("img").getAttribute('src');

    switch (james)
    {
        case "12.jpg":
            document.getElementById("img").src = "13.jpg";
            break;

        case "13.jpg":
            document.getElementById("img").src = "14.jpg";
            break;

        default: 
            alert('Default case');
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are picking the source attribute in a global level statement

```
var james = document.getElementById("img").getAttribute('src');
```

which is executed only once.

Try to initialize in the function first pic

```
function FirstPic(){
    var james = document.getElementById("img").getAttribute('src');

    switch (james)
    {
       ....
    }
}
```

Hope that helps. :)